# I can't print the names with matrix container is there any possibility for print the names using a matrix?

Tags: c#, matrix

```
public void PrintNames() 
{
    string[,] matrix = new string[3, 3]; 
    Console.WriteLine("write a name:");
    string a = Console.ReadLine(); 
    Console.WriteLine("write a name:");
    string b = Console.ReadLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int x  = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} row {1} component {2} name", i +1,x+1, matrix[i, x]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am a really beginner programmer and I'd like to finish my homework.
My problem is I can't print the names which I wrote in the console. For example: Please write a name: Jhon Wick (enter)
Please write a name: Kyle (enter)
thereafter I'd like to print: 1. Row 1. component Jhon Wick
  1. Row 2. component Kyle

Comment: I have to write a 3x3 matrix without using a jagged matrix .string[,] matrix = new string[3, 3];        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                         for (int x  = 0; x < 3; x++) i used this for cycle

Comment: Please add this code to your question (edit it), and better yet - add the full code you wrote, so it'd be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay, I will insert the full code.

Comment: Can you see your problem now? Hint: After the variables `a` and `b` are filled with user input, you'd want to put them inside your `matrix`.

Comment: ooh, I see thank you for helping!